# Add a sub-spinner to a spinner's item when pressed (spinner item grouping)

Tags: android, spinner

I'm developing a bus times application and I want to create a sub-spinner when one of the root spinner items is pressed. The root spinner will contain route numbers (1, 29, 149 etc) and the sub-spinner will contain the city of the route.

Here's an example I made in photoshop:

[image: image 1]

As you can see not all routes has a city selection. Now after we press "29":

[image: img 2]

I'm really struggling on how to implement this, does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

For **spinner I don't know**, but If you want to try within listView then try [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), which allows you to have two levels of expansion.

[Example of Expandable lists](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html)